# No Updates found for Canopy 1.5

Tags: enthought

I am trying to update my canopy (v 1.4.1 (64 bit)) to 1.5 but in the about page it says no updates are found. I would like to avoid re-downloading. Is there a possible work-around?

Comment: Notice to vigilant SO would-be censors: Enthought Canopy is a Python programming environment, for which Stack Overflow is the main locus of public support. Therefore this question is on-topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry for the inconvenience. We have temporarily disabled in-application updates because of extreme server burden from repeated update downloads in a few atypical environments.

At present, to update Canopy, it's necessary to uninstall the application (on Windows use Control Panel; on Mac delete from Applications; on Linux delete the install dir). Then download the Canopy 1.5.1 (or higher) installer from https://store.enthought.com/downloads/, and install it.

***Your Canopy User Python environment is in a separate directory and will not be modified unless you separately, explicitly delete it -- in this respect the effects of this Canopy reinstallation are exactly the same as with an in-app Canopy update. Likewise, your preferences and saved sessions will not be affected.***

[Edit March 2015]: The server burden vulnerability was fixed in Canopy 1.5.2, released 28 January 2015. After you update to 1.5.2, future updates should again be possible in-application. See https://support.enthought.com/hc/en-us/articles/204469570-Canopy-shows-no-updates-available-reinstalling-from-the-website

Thanks for your patience.

-- Enthought Support